# MPAudioPlayerController interrupted by Home button can not save state

Tags: objective-c, ios5.1, mpmusicplayercontroller

Using the AppDelegate, we respond to notifications:

**applicationWillResignActive** and **applicationDidBecomeActive**

In our main routine, the above calls trigger ***saveAudioState*** and ***restoreAudioState*** respectively.  These grab the state of the AudioPlayer and then resume when we come back from the interruption.  This works ok on phone interruptions, but not on Home button presses.

In the Home button case, the values for currentTime and currentAudioItem are invalid.

```
- (void) saveAudioState {
    currentAudioItem = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;
    currentTime = musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime;
    NSLog(@"Playback state %d", musicPlayer.playbackState);
    NSLog(@"Time %f", currentTime);
    NSLog(@"Track %@", currentAudioItem);
    audioWasPlaying = NO;
    if (musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
        audioWasPlaying = YES;
        [musicPlayer pause];
    }
}

- (void) restoreAudioState {
    // Restore the now-playing item and its current playback time.
    musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem          = currentAudioItem;
    musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime     = currentTime;

    // If the music player was playing, get it playing again.
    if (audioWasPlaying && currentAudioItem) {
        [musicPlayer play];
    }
}
```

Is this a bug with iOS or just a result of how things get torn down?

I have tested on iOS 5.1 and 5.1.1.

Comment: Have you tried `-applicationWillResignActive:` and `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` of the app delegate class?

Comment: Yes, that is where the above code is called from.  Apparently something about the home button / timing destroys the MusicPlayer info prior to those notifications.